Phusion passenger on Nginx not serving application on Port 80. Basically times out
I have been banging my head on the desk on this for quite some time.
I have used the following guide to deploy my small Ruby on Rails application to a Digital Ocean droplet and run the app on a Nginx / Phusion passenger web server: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/22.04
Everything works fine up until I add the phusion passenger piece to the nginx config file.
After I install nginx and start it. I can access my droplet IP and I see the "Welcome to Nginx screen"
Once I ass the phusion passenger bits and pieces to the server block for my app, when I try to reach my droplet IP, it just sits there and eventually times out.
Things I have already checked

Make sure the firewall of my droplet allows Port 80 through (it was off but I added port 80)
Make sure the local firewall on Ubuntu 22 is not running (It's not)
Looked at the /var/log/nginx/error.log for errors (There aren't any)
Navigated to my application folder and executed: bundle exec passenger start (It starts without errors on port 3000)
Ran an online port scanning on my droplet IP and it shows Port 80 and 22 open

Here is the content of my nginx file that is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  passenger_preload_bundler on;
  client_max_body_size 100m;


  location ~ ^/(asets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

}

Here is the content of the /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;
passenger_log_level 6;
passenger_log_file /var/log/nginx/passenger.log;

I've added the last 2 lines in order to obtain a bit more granular logs in an attempt to see an error.
I've gone through multiple trials and errors reading other posts and other suggestions but it's still not working.
EDIT
If I shutdown nginx and start the Puma rails server using bundle exec rails s --binding my.server.ip.address , it works. I can access my site through xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 (Of course I had to temporarily switch config.force_ssl to false in my production.rb file)
So I'm really not sure why passenger (or nginx) doesn't start my server

For anyone who would be stuck in the same situation. The solution is so simple. I was trying to test my site using NGINX on a Digital Ocean droplet as soon as I deployed it. My domain name wasn't even pointed to the droplet's IP Address and I had not ordered and installed the SSL certificate for my site yet
I was therefore trying to test my Ruby on Rails site on port 80
But Rails (at least Rails 7) comes baked in with a little line in the configuration that forces the site to be served on SSL only.
config.force_ssl = true

So no matter what I tried, it would never work on Port 80 until I changed it to
config.force_ssl = false

I was then able to test the connection and general use for my site on port 80.
Once I installed the SSL certificate and got NGINX listening on Port 443, I reverted to
config.force_ssl = true

